# Cooking Measurements in C# / F#

Tags: c#, f#, units-of-measurement

Do any of you know a library for the representation and calculation of cooking units  (Cup, Tablespoon, Gallon...) in C# or F# (especially in regard to culture, metric/imperial)?

Comment: What are "cooking units"? e.g. That chicken is 43 units cooked?

Comment: Google "c# unit conversion library" and have a look at those

Comment: @Ben, think he means how to convert from cup, to deciliter, centiliter etc :-)

Comment: @Ben What Fredrik says. :) How much tablespoons are a cup for instance.

Comment: This conversation makes me giggle like a small child, must be tired today :-)

Comment: If you want to build some util to convert e.g. weight units to more "cooking units", then you should check this: http://www.cookiemaster.org/.

Comment: @Fredrik Well, it's not the usual LOB-App-question for sure. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Units of measure are built into the F# language:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx

They can be easily extended with custom units, as long as you know conversion ratios.

Edit: Of course, you might end up with some strange unit types to account between differences in weights and volumes (the ratio of 1 cup of flour to 1 cup of water is not the same as the ratio of 100g of flour to 100g of water...)

Comment: Comparing cup to grams is like comparing liters to kilos. The first is a volume measure, the second is a weight measure. They are non-interchangeable units of measure.

Comment: @Abel: It would seem you haven't dealt much with international recipes.  In the US, recipes specify amounts of flour in terms of cups.  In other places, recipes specify amounts of flour in terms of grams.  A good cooking application should know how to make these kinds of conversions.

Comment: @Abel the challenge is that they are interchangeable when dealing with the same material (the ratio of cups of flour to grams of flour is constant), but not when you deal with different materials. And as noted by Eric, you often need to convert between them when dealing with recipes from different people/places.

Comment: So as I see it some manual work is in order. I'll have a look at F#, thanks.

Comment: I think the best way to do it would be to pick either volume or weight as the primary, and then do units for ingredient type for the other.

Comment: i.e. if you're UK based (like myself), define a CupOfFlour unit and CupOfWater unit, both defined in terms of grams. This will spawn a multitude of units, though.